# Generic question about obtaining arc trig functions..

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

First post here, and it's rather simple and generic..

In one of my Calc II problems, in trig substitutions, I've come across the following while solving for theta while back-substituting:

$$ x=2sec\theta $$

$$ \frac x2 = sec\theta $$

$$ \theta = arcsec(\frac x2) $$

My question is, is this a general rule for dividing trig functions from one side to the other? Would be great to know. There are a million little tid-bits like this I've failed to pick up along the way, which adds to my frustration. Trying to make up for that now.

Thanks for anyone who has the time to give an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "dividing". You're applying the function $\operatorname{arcsec}$ to each side of the equation $x/2 = \sec \theta$, which results in the equation $\operatorname{arcsec}(x/2) = \operatorname{arcsec}(\sec \theta) = \theta$ because $\operatorname{arcsec}$ is the inverse function of $\sec$.

Comment: Makes total sense! Thanks.